# How to hide show div by using dynamic id in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

My code as below in html file:

```
<ul class="main-icons"  ng-if="showMainIcons">
   <li ng-repeat="programData in tab.data">
      <img src="{{programData.icon}}"
           ng-click="programClicked($event,programData,tab)">
       // some another codes
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="details-icons"  ng-show="tab.data.id"> 
   // some codes
</ul>
```

code in controller

```
$scope.programClicked = function($event,programData, tabData) {

        var newVar =  tabData.data.id;
        $scope.newVar = true;
        $scope.showMainIcons = false;
}
```

I am displaying multiple tabs, now in one tab if I click on some icon it will display the details, instead of this it is displaying all tabs details, not particular tab and I have to pass param in function while using ng-click

also I tried to pass the flag variable true/ false, its also displaying all tabs as like in controller

```
$scope.showDetails = true; 
$scope.showMainIcons = false
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You realize that this `var newVar =  tabData.id;` is never used?

Comment: you are looping over `tab.data`, so I guess `tab.data` is an array. And you are writing `tab.data.id` in `ng-show` - shouldn't it be something like `tab.data[0].id`? I meant shouldn't you use an index to access that?

Comment: @Chris it is my way, that I am implemented this way, its not working, I need and idea, how to display div by using dynamic id

Comment: @ArnabRoy, yes, its so, its bunch of multiple array, I am getting it by ng-repeat, I want to display div by passing dynamic id, if I pass same variable name or id, then it is displaying all tabs at a time, I want if I click on particular tab, then on particular tab data will display

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your html code is :

```
<ul class="details-icons"  ng-show="tab.data.id"> 
   // some codes
</ul>
```

so here you are using:  "tab.data.id"
but in controller you are using : var newVar =  tabData.id; I think it should : var newVar =  tab.data.id;

Comment: I used the same way in html, and I am passing tab varibale from html and getting this value in tabData varibale. When I tried this way then its not working